# Mass with triple integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

The triple integral that represents the mass of a solid right circular cylinder $T$ of radius $4$ and height $3$ given that the density varies directly with half the distance from the axis of the cylinder is :

This is an easy question but I got confused a bit about"density varies directly with half the distance from the axis of the cylinder" this will be density.  Is means $r^=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot 1/2.$ If so, this answer is $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{4}\int_0^{3} r^3 dz dr d\theta$$ Is that correct?

Comment: Why not $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{4}\int_0^{3} (r/2) rdz dr d\theta$?

Comment: @RobertZ, I might miss something obvious. How is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that to say that “the density varies directly with half the distance from the axis of the cylinder” means that the function that should be $\frac12\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ (as you wrote), and then the integral should be$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^4\int_0^3\frac12r^2\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta.$$

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake should be $r^2$ not $r^3$